# How to expand lines in Vim Latex

Tags: vim, latex

As you can see when I open a LaTeX file in vim, lines are folded up.

How can I expand them at once?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zR` (folding reduce all) opens all folds; alternatively, `zi` toggles folding on/off. Look around in that `:help` page; there are many more folding-related commands.

If you want to automatically start with a certain fold state

```
:set foldlevelstart=99
```

opens with all folds opened. To influence that for certain buffers, use the `'foldlevel'` option in a *filetype plugin*.

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious, "that help page" is `:help fold.txt`